# Firebase database observer does not retrieve data

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an iOS App that uses Firebase to store user information. I cannot seem to get the `observe()` block ran in anyway. The closure is never executed.

When I debug the code, I see that the `observe()` block is skipped hence I cannot validate the user information.

From the Firebase console, I can verify a table with a name equal to `hashCode` exists and the table in fact has a `checked` field.

I use Xcode 9.3 and Swift 4.1

What am I missing here?

Thanks

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // UI changes
    self.view.backgroundColor = appBgColour

    // check if the user has registered before
    if let asciiCode = defaults.string(forKey: "asciiCode") {
        let hashCode = userCode.myHash() // myHash() is an extension to String

        dbReference = Database.database().reference(withPath: databaseReferenceName)

        dbReference.child("\(hashCode)/checked").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
                // a table with this user's Hash'ed code exists
                self.isRegistrationNeeded = false
            } else {
                // user needs to register with a new list
                self.isRegistrationNeeded = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, it is normal that the closure is skipped. Since data is loaded from Firebase asynchronously and takes time, the closure is only invoked "much" later. To see if it is invoked, place a breakpoint inside the closure on your `if snapshot.exists() {` line.

Comment: Thanks. When I run the App, it always takes me to the login screen, which is presented (in `viewDidAppear()`) in case the value of `isRegistrationNeeded` is `true`. Within my ViewController class, I initialize the value of `isRegistrationNeeded` member variable to `true` and my assumption is that the `observe()` block is not executed when the App is running (in the simulator). Do you reckon this could be the case?